# How to split large sql insert into multiple inserts

Tags: mysql

I have large sql insert query with multiple inserts seperated by commas something like below.

```
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (396,3,90,'collar','admin','2015-05-27 10:10:52','2015-05-27 10:10:52',0),(397,3,90,'across shoulder','admin','2015-05-27 10:10:52','2015-05-27 10:10:52',0);
```

How can I split this large sql insert into multiple inserts?

Some thing like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES(396,3,90,'collar','admin','2015-05-27 10:10:52','2015-05-27 10:10:52',0);
INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (397,3,90,'across shoulder','admin','2015-05-27 10:10:52','2015-05-27 10:10:52',0);
```

Comment: Are you using a programming language?  If not, you just answered your own question about how to break up a multiple `INSERT`.

Comment: You can, for example, launch your first query on a test database and after that export with your client "export assistant" WITHOUT the option "bulk". As Tim said, we need know how (MySQL, programming, user actions) do you want to do this.

Comment: @EnriqueMuñoz Yeah! Thats what I have done for now.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option are avaialble.(This are Only alternatives)

`1) Create CSV file of Inputs and import it into table by using Workbench.`

or

`2) I will suggest you alternative to this use Mysql WorkBench for insert values.`